# Select only specific parts of the image

Tags: php, ocr

I am completely new in "Optical character recognition" and need some more information and advices because I was not able to find is it possible to do what I need.

I have the following task:

1. An images are given as input - they will have the same structure -
   some icons and company symbols and text.
2. Only the text need to be selected and then make as text using some
   OCR library.

Is it possible to create a function using some OCR php library and select only some of the zones with text?

If there is not good OCR library for PHP, could you recommend me some on other languages?

The example below demonstrates what I want to do (this is just an example, I am not trying to do some out of the law manipulations with money):

This is sample image:

[image]

And this is the output (the text surrounded with red rectangles):

1. THIS IS LEGAL TENDER FOR ALL DEBTS, PUBLIC AND PRIVATE
2. L11180916G
3. ONEDOLAR

All articles and advices are welcomed.

Comment: Certainly not off-topic question is clearly asking for development help to get the text out of image using a php.

Comment: @MubasharAhmad No, I was not able to find a way to extract it. A long time ago, one stackoverflow user share a link to his tool, which can do this, but it was not free and I do not try it. Later, he has deleted his answer.

Comment: @gotqn Apparently the solution was called "ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK", though I do not know if it 1. even works or 2. is worth the price.

Comment: I would recommend the python scientific ecosystem. The libraries and tutorials are very good, and ipython notebook (now jupyter) helps tremendously when debugging image workflows. A good start is one of the scipy tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olb7R1cuzyU

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

PHP probably not the best tool for the job, but you can always call tesseract from PHP if you want to, then parse the results that you get out of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any PHP extension implementing OCR, but as a generic scrpting language with support for image manipulation, PHP is an excellent choice for integrating other tools.

[Tesseract and gocr](https://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2010-06/15-linux_ocr_software_comparison) are open source command line tools for OCR, both very effective. But like any OCR package will likely struggle with an image similar to the one you provided. If your PHP code can isolate the text the text regions, then you'll get much better results. You will still have to do some data cleansing - use a php spell checker. You'll find the same patterns of misreading keep cropping up - like reading 'rn' as 'm'. Your PHP code should be able to identify and handle most cases.

Regarding the problem of identifying text areas - it depends how similar the documents really are. If you tune your application using $1 bills it may be able to read the serial numbers from lots of them - but it won't know how to read a different note. There are lots of image recognition tools available, and again, the cli tools will be easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Irfanview **32-bit** and then install the KADMOS plugin:
http://irfanview.info/plugins/kadmos/

The DLL of Kadmos --at least for the plugin-- is currently 32-bit and that's why it only works with the 32-bit edition of Irfanview.

Once installed, open an image displaying some text and select the "Options > Start OCR ... (plugin)" menu entry. Then, you'll be able to select some text by dragging and dropping a rectangle around it, and the regognized text will pop up in a window from which you can copy it.
The plugin is for personal (non commercial) use only, but let you see if KADMOS suits your needs.

If you have many pictures to process batch, you could acquire a license of Kadmos DLL.
For technical documentation, see: http://www.best-ocr.com/handbuch/book/html/files.html
For licensing questions, replace "files.html" by "dll_e.htm" in the URL above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Abbyy Cloud Ocr Sdk**
https://cloud.ocrsdk.com/

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but it may help someone else. Try ClearImage SDK.

http://www.inliteresearch.com/actions/download-proc.php?type=CI&id=

```
try {
    $Ci = new COM("ClearImage.ClearImage");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```